# what does it mean "Wifi Watchdog Service (android.server.ServerThread) does not require the watchdog"?

Tags: android

I have implemented one application which talks over TCP/IP to the server via Wi-Fi, it has to talk to server even device goes to sleep mode so for that I implemented Partial wake lock so even though device goes to sleep mode CPU will be turned on so Wi-Fi also be turned on.

Problem: If I keep the device for longer duration around 7-8 hrs idle with my application running , it seems like device goes to deep sleep mode and when i checked the logcat i found the message  : "Wifi Watchdog Service (android.server.ServerThread) for wifi does not require the watchdog".
Not able to undertsand  why this message display for the router?

Can anyone put some good inputs regarding this?

Regards,
Piks